# Is uniform continuity necessary here?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

The following problem appears in *Linear Functional Analysis* by Rynne and Youngson as a worked example. I tend to do these on my own first, and my solution differs from that in the book because I don't see the need to use the *absolute continuity of the function k*.  Am I right?

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, let $k:[a,b]\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ be continuous. If $g\in C[a,b]$, show that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$f(s)=\int_a^bk(s,t)g(t)dt$$
is in $C[a,b]$.

I approach this as follows. Since $g$ is continuous on a compact interval, let $M=\lVert g\rVert_{\infty}$.

By hypothesis, $\exists$ $\delta>0:\lVert(s_1,t_1)-(s_2,t_2)\rVert<\delta$   $\Rightarrow$   $|$ $k(s_1,t_1)-k(s_2,t_2)|<\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)M}$.

Since $\lVert(s_1,t)-(s_2,t)\rVert=|s_1-s_2|$  $\forall t$, we have $$|s_1-s_2|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(s_1)-f(s_2)|\leqslant\int_a^b|k(s_1,t)-k(s_2,t)||g(t)|dt\leqslant\int_a^b\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)M}|g(t)|dt\leqslant(b-a)M\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)M}=\epsilon$$

As mentioned, this seems to hold regardless of $\delta$ being unique to $s_1$ and $s_2$, and it holds for all $t$.

*Source: Example 4.7 part (a) and own solution.*

Comment: I guess you meant to write $\lvert s_1-s_2\rvert<\delta$? (If not, I think you should have) Then, it seems to me that the fact that $\delta$ grants a bound for all $t$ is the very reason allowing you to substitute $\lvert k(s_1,t)-k(s_2,t)\rvert$ with a constant.

Comment: Yes indeed - it should be $\delta$, which I've now corrected.   

I have aimed to show that $\delta$ depends only on $s$ by virtue of cancellation rather than uniform continuity.  (It also depends on the $\epsilon$ multiple, of course.)

Comment: You don't need full uniform continuity, but to have a $\delta > 0$ that works for all $t$ you need some uniformity. If you precisely state the "By hypothesis" line, it should become apparent that you need more than just the continuity of $k$ on a product space.

Comment: I've clarified the hypothesis to say $\lVert(s_1,t_1)-(s_2,t_2)\rVert$ rather than $\lVert(s_1,t)-(s_2,t)\rVert$. However, this is irrelevant in view of the fact that the 2-norm does not depend on $t$ if $t_1 = t_2$.

Comment: What parameters enter into the existence of $\delta$? In "For all (stuff) there is $\delta > 0$ ...", what is (stuff)?

Comment: $\delta$ as described exists for all positive reals, and in particular for the value on the right-hand side of that line, just before the full stop. $\epsilon$ is itself an arbitrary positive real, which is often unspoken.